# Forcing flexbox element to float right

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm currently working on responsiveness on my website and I hit the wall. On smaller resolutions I changed the `flex-direction` to `column` from `row`, changed the ordering of flex elements, changed the main textbox `width` to `100%` and sideboxes to `50%`.

Code looks like this:

```
<section class="about" id="ABOUT">
    <div class="about-sidebox l">
    </div>

    <div class="about-mainbox">
    </div>

    <div class="about-sidebox r">
    </div>
</section>
```

As you can see the sideboxes are not within the container. Putting them in container helps but completely ruins my previous layout.

CSS for wanted resolution is:

```
.about {
    flex-direction: column;
}

.about-mainbox {
    order: 1;
}

.about-sidebox {
    order: 2;
    width: 50%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Effect is like this:
[image]

As you can see I want the sideboxes to be next to each other. Any solution I can't think of without adding additional container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've understood you correctly. You could remove the `flex-direction` property from `.about`

Add `flex-wrap`. Then just give `.about-mainbox` a `width` of 100%

```css
.about {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.about-mainbox {
  order: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

.about-sidebox {
  order: 2;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section class="about" id="ABOUT">
  <div class="about-sidebox l">demo left
  </div>
  <div class="about-mainbox">demo
  </div>
  <div class="about-sidebox r">demo right
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I almost thought that id doesn't work but had to remove "flex: 2" from the mainbox and it works like a charm! Thanks for saving me tons of time rebuilding things, I don't know why I didn't went with simple widths instead of "flex: NUMBER"

Answer (score 1):

The simplest possible is to do this;

- Set the `about` to `flex-wrap: wrap` so its flex items can wrap, skip `flex-direction` so it uses its default `row`
- Set the `mainbox` to `order: -1` (default is `0`), which will position it before the `sidebox`'s, and `flex-basis: 100%`, which will make it take full width and by doing that, it pushes the `sidebox`'s to a new line
- Give the `sidebox`'s `flex-basis: 50%` to be equally wide, and `min-width: 0;` so they stay side-by-side (if you wan't them to wrap and stack vertical when their content force's them to, drop this, or control it with a set width, i.e. `min-width: 150px;`)

*I also recommend you use Flexbox's own properties, i.e. in this case `flex-basis` instead of `width`*

```css
.about {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.about-mainbox {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  order: -1;
}

.about-sidebox {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="about" id="ABOUT">

  <div class="about-sidebox l">Left
  </div>

  <div class="about-mainbox">Main
  </div>

  <div class="about-sidebox r">Right
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Got it, changed width to flex-basis, thanks for the tip!